# Get substring from end to certain character in python

Tags: python, string, substring, substr

I want to get the substring from a path from the end to a certain character, take for example the following path:

**my_path = "/home/Desktop/file.txt"**

My intention is to do something like:

```
my_path.substring(end,"/")
```

So I can get the name of the file that is located between the **end** of the string and the character **"/"**, in this case **"file.txt"**

Comment: Have you had a look at the `os.path` module, specifically the [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) function?

Comment: Use `pathlib`. `from pathlib import Path; Path("/home/Desktop/file.txt").name == "file.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach, IMHO, would be to split the string:

```
filename = my_path.split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `os.path.basename` for this

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.path.basename('/home/Desktop/file.txt')
Out[2]: 'file.txt'
```